# jquery - get first occurence of selection

Tags: jquery, selection

How can i determine if  first occurance (element 0) of  contains text "No Errors"

```
if ($(xml).find('errors')[0].text() == 'No Errors') 
{
  do something
}
```

!!! edit !!!

```
 found it...

 if ($(xml).find('error').first().text() == 'No errors')
```

Comment: What does your demo mark-up look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `[0]` causes JavaScript/jQuery to return the DOM node, instead of the jQuery object, you might try:

```
if ($(xml).find('.errors:first').text() == 'No Errors') 
{
  // do something
}
```

Or:

```
if ($(xml).find('.errors').eq(0).text() == 'No Errors') 
{
  // do something
}
```

Both of these `if` statements require that the text *is*, not simply *contains*, equal to `'No Errors'`.

To test that the text *contains* the text 'No Errors':

```
if ($(xml).find('.errors').eq(0).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('no errors') > -1) 
{
  // do something
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GpvPT/).

References:

- [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score 1):

Using brackets will give you the DOM element; you need the jQuery object so you can use `.text()` on it. To test for equality:

`if ($(xml).find('errors:first').text() == "No Errors")`

To test for containment:

`if ($(xml).find('errors:first').text().indexOf("No Errors") > -1)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if ($(xml).find('errors').first().text().indexOf('No Errors') != -1)
{
  do something
}
```

Changes:

1. Use `first()` to get a jQuery object of the first matched element, not a DOM object
2. Use `indexOf()` on the text to see if 'No Errors' is anywhere inside
3. Compare to -1 to see if it's there

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(xml).find('errors').eq(0).text() == 'No Errors') 
{
  do something
}
```